# How to stay logged in via SSH to a Synology Server?

Tags: ssh, process, synology

How do I stay logged in continuously to a Synology (custom Linux) server via SSH? I am trying to get a program to run continuously on the server but when I close my SSH window from my own computer, the program also gets killed. Any ways around it? Thanks.

Comment: Background the task with 'nohup foo.sh &'. No need to leave SSH connection open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `screen` utility. If you're using Debian or Ubuntu based distros, install it via `sudo apt-get install screen`. To run it, type `screen`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the information screen. Run your commands here.

If you ever disconnect, you can get back by typing `screen -rd` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will bring you back to the session that is still running. Great for moving your session to another terminal or SSH connection.

Comment: So if I were to run the screen program, do my commands, then exit using `exit`, then `exit` again to close the ssh window would that kill the program?

Comment: Exit will close your session. If you want it running in the background, press ctrl d after starting the program

Comment: Option 2, close the session and open a new ssh connection. Screen will keep running

Comment: How can this be the answer, OP is specifically about Synology which does not have 'apt'

Comment: @GregWoods I don't mention running `screen` on the Synology, but on the local system, assuming they're running Linux. I do not use Synology, but I use a lot of SSH, so that's one method I used.

Comment: @CanadianLuke yep... kinda seems obvious now!

Answer (score 0):

From another Linux you can simply do this by running the command without a pty (ie no ssh -t option):

```
ssh syno 'sleep 999 </dev/null >&/dev/null &'
```

I don't use windows nor putty but if that is your case I see there is a command *plink* in the putty suite that is similar:

```
plink -ssh -l root -i mykey.ppk syno 'sleep 999 </dev/null >&/dev/null &'
```

Alternatively, you should be able to run your command from within putty with

```
nohup sleep 999 </dev/null &
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of 'nohup' and 'screen' are good solutions to make sure that a job you manually start keeps on running.

If you want your process to survive reboots, you have to make sure it starts after reboot.
There are several solutions for that.
On my Synology station I discovered that files starting with "S" in the '/volume1/startup' directory are run as startup scripts in the 'init.d' directory.
You can see that in the '/etc/rc' script:

```
/etc/rc:        if [ -d /volume1/startup ]; then
/etc/rc:                for startsh in /volume1/startup/S* ; do
```

which works if /etc/synoinfo.conf has

```
supportstartupd="yes"
```

That would also survive Synology system reinstalls.